# How do we call the line on video/audio player where we see how much of file has been loaded?

Tags: multimedia

Look at the example image taken from YouTube

[image]

When I watch video file or listen to audio file, there is always a horizontal like which shows how much video/audio has been cached as well as my current location in video/audio.

What is this line called in plain English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only going to get opinions with your question. There is no 'set' word, it's just how different people know it / refer to it.

Personally, a progress bar or timeline. I assume *timeline* would be more accurate of the two.

You may want to ask https://english.stackexchange.com/ as this is for English.

Answer (score 3):

The most common term for it that I know of is *seek bar*, though some media players (like VLC) call it *track slider*.

In audio/video editing terminology, the word used for it is *timeline*. A few related terms include the *playhead*, which is the symbol that marks your current position on the timeline, and *scrubbing*, which refers to moving the playhead manually across the timeline.

Comment: I've always heard it called the seek bar.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard it called a "Buffering Bar" on many occasions.

Dave is right though in saying that it will vary from person to person.